# Multithreading slows down with more cores

Tags: java, multithreading, sieve-of-eratosthenes

Im trying to implement Eratosthenes prime sieve with multithreading.
The threads are taken care of by a treadpool

```
ThreadPoolExecutor executor = 
    new ThreadPoolExecutor(
        6,   // cores
        10,  // threads
        1000,
        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, 
        new ArrayBlockingQueue<Runnable>(n)
    );
```

And the sieve it self is implemented like this

```
for (int i=2; i<Math.sqrt(n); i++ ){
    if (list[i].get()) { // boolean list initialized earlier
        executor.execute(new Calc(i,n));
    }
}
```

with the run method looking like this

```
public void run(){
    for (int j=start*2;j<n;j=j+start){ 
        list[j].set(false); 
    }   
}
```

Now, what i dont understand is why, when the `corePoolSize` is lower (other parameters stay the same), the program runs faster. (2 cores 2.5 Milliseconds; 7 - 3.3; etc.).
I think i might be making some rookie mistake, but i dont understand why this is happening?

EDIT:
Full class looks like this (have to use a single class for the cluster, hence everything is in Main:

```
int start;
int n;
Main(int start,int n){
    this.start=start;
    this.n=n;
}
public void run(){
            for (int j=start*2;j<n;j=j+start){
                list[j].set(true);
            }


        }


private static list myBoolean[];

   public static void main(String[] args) {
    int  n = 20000;     
    list= new AtomicBoolean[n+1];


for (int i=2; i<n; i++ ){
            list[i]=new AtomicBoolean(false);
       }
      ThreadPoolExecutor executor = 
                new ThreadPoolExecutor(
                        7,
                    10,
                    1000,
                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, 
                    new ArrayBlockingQueue<Runnable>(n));

    long startedTime = System.nanoTime();
    for (int i=2; i<Math.sqrt(n); i++ ){
        if (list[i]){
            executor.execute(new Main(i,n));
        }
    }   

    executor.shutdown();
    try {
        executor.awaitTermination(60, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }   
    System.out.println("Work time "+(float)(System.nanoTime()-startedTime)/1000000+" s.");

    }

}
```

Comment: How many cores does your hardware actually have?

Comment: my computer has 7; but i also tried running it on a... computer cluster? Im not sure what its actually called in english, sorry! But you can choose the core size there, i tried it with various ones and the core count in the program matched the core size in the cluster. Results where the same

Comment: I hope you're using [`AtomicBoolean`s](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicBoolean.html) in your `list` to avoid race conditions and concurrent modification.

Comment: It is worth reading the scala doc (while not java directly) has details - http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/futures.html

Comment: I think a good answer cannot be given. We have only pieces of codes, it's not reproductible. Plus, your runnable looks like it blindly modify a global array state, which is very bad. And, to test performance on such a little use-case, A simple java main is not a good thing (just starting JVM + initializing thread pool might take 99% of yout run time). You need a real benchmark  framework here

Comment: @user1121883 not correct. The visibility isn't guaranteed, and while you could make a regular `boolean` `volatile`, you can't make the elements of an array `volatile`.

Comment: @ amanin I changed it to AtomicBoolean, my bad.  Also, the timer starts at just before the sieve (second code bit), rather than at the very start

Comment: @murksluke yes, but what if there's lazy initialization ? Maybe the executor pop a thread on the system only when it's asked for it, so a program using more threads can be less performant, if the cost of creating the threads is higher than the cost of the processing. And due to the simplicity of your code (setting booleans in an array), it might be the case here.

Comment: As a side note, I don't think `AtomicBoolean` is the right choice here, if you share the same list instance with multiple threads and write to it, you have to synchronize the list, not the values in the list. I don't think you access the same list entries from different threads at the same time!?

Comment: @amanin i added the full class

Comment: @xander i think i could - for example list[12] will be accessed by 2,3,4,6-th threads

Comment: @amanin i wildly increased the sieves upper bound and the run time seems to have leveled out a lot - it even a bit longer with less cores! Is that what you mean 'if the cost of creating the threads is higher than the cost of the processing'?

Comment: Creating a thread is costly. By reading ThreadPoolExecutor javadoc, It states that "even core threads are initially created and started only when new tasks arrive". That means the first times you call execute, the pool will  create a new thread, then run your Runnable in it. When the thread pool is full, or has idle threads, it re-use previously created threads, so it becomes less costly to execute a task. But, I want to say comething else : a lot of things can impact performances (synchronisation, JIT, gc, etc.), so my answer is surely only a part of the phenomenon you see.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends a lot on how many cores you have. If you have 2 cores and you want to execute on 7 threads will just make the things slower because of the thread context switching. This is called Amdahl's law.

Also is worth mentioning that the first 2 parameters for the executor constructor are  corePoolSize and maximumPoolSize [java doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html#ThreadPoolExecutor(int,%20int,%20long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit,%20java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue)) `corePoolSize` means  the number of threads to keep in the pool, even if they are idl while `maximumPoolSize` is  the maximum number of threads to allow in the pool

Anyways the main reason is that the only thing you are measuring is how much it takes for the executor to shut down. You initialize the array with false:  `list[i]=new AtomicBoolean(false);`
Then the only situation you create a task for the thread pool is when you find a true element  `if (list[i]){`. since there is no true element this will never happen so no task will be scheduled/executed.

Comment: downvoter please let me know what is wrong so I'll delete my answer if it doesn't make any sense

Comment: Makes sense to me.

Comment: but if i am increasing the core size, and not the threads, wouldnt it become faster?

Comment: I don't think Amdahl's law is relevant here - it never describes a *decrease* in performance, it only describes the *increase* from adding more resources and the *limit* imposed by the sequential section of the code. It doesn't take into account overhead from implementation details like context switching, which is the real issue as you say.

Comment: @murksiuke the first parameter is corePoolSize and the second is maximumPoolSize. This means when there is a long queue of task thread pool will create more threads and give them load

Comment: @user1121883 sorry, im still not sure why that would lead to slowing down with more cores. Even if the running thread count increases since there are more cores, the running thread/core ratio would still stay more or less the same and that law wouldnt come into play?

Comment: @murksiuke added details regarding what corePoolSize means. The question is how many cores does your CPU has? the best performance will be with the same number of threads as CPU core (theoretical)

Comment: ...oh. Well that explains some things. I will check if thats why im getting weird results

Comment: @user1121883 i tried running it on a computer cluster (still have no idea if thats what its called in english, sorry!) where i can choose how many cores i run it with, and even if i match the corePoolSize with the core size im using, 2 cores still run faster, than, lets say, 12.

Comment: other than what I already said I'm pretty sure another issue may be the synchronization. can you post full code so we also see if you have any? if you run the method that does the execute before any threads start processing I'm pretty sure all values in the array are true

Comment: @murksiuke It also may be the case that all the difference it is related to the number of threads the program creates. how much does it take the initialization of the thread pool?

Comment: @user1121883 i posted the full code, as you can see the timer starts after the threadpool initialization, since the i only want to see how long it takes to go through the sieve

Comment: @murksiuke please see the last edit. Your code won't create any task.

Comment: @user1121883 yes, my bad! I already fixed it in my code, but forgot to do so in here

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169434/discussion-between-user1121883-and-murksiuke).

Comment: @user1121883 Actually, i think there is no need - just did some testing, 10 cores are a good way faster than 6. Thanks for the help!